# SQL Server find and replace words mentioned in the another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table [selection] that has columns Id, Id_purchase and Id_employee. Id is primary key and all is type int.

```
Id | Id_purchase | Id_employee
1  |     1       |   1
```

A table [employees] has Id_employee (int) and name is varchar(250)

```
Id_employee |  name
1           |  name1
2           |  name2
3           |  name3
```

A table [purchase] has Id_purchase (int) and article is varchar(250)

```
Id_purchase |      article 
   1        |  book1 pattern ABC 
   2        |  book2 autor hjk abc
   3        |  book3 about xyz
   4        |  book4 JJJJ
```

and a table [key_search] has Id and query is varchar(100).

```
ID  |  query 
1   | book*abc
2   | book*about
```

How for each employee from [employees] create record to add to the table [selection] IDs of all purchases from the table [Purchase] in which there are words mentioned in the table [key_search].
In a table [key_search]  " * " considered a substitute for any number of characters. For sample a query like "book*abc" need REPLACE to "%book%abc%" for seach in all purchase.

Comment: Further please clarify ,this part "How for each employee to add to the table [selection] IDs of all new purchases from the table [Purchase] in which there are words mentioned in the table [key_search].
In a table [key_search] mark * considered a substitute for any number of characters."

Comment: With plain `SQL` this will be a pain. Look for `CLR` function that will receive string and a pattern. Then do the replace logic in C# code and return edited value. Probably you will need 2 `CLR` functions, one for checking for match which you will use in `WHERE` clause and second is for replace, which you will use in `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: Yes, CLR function is easy, but need solved only sql.

Comment: The Best solution would involve normalizing the data in the Key_Search table an separate it to 2 different tables.
If you can't do this, you can create a dynamic insert statement.

Comment: @yurikod I changed my answer. Give it a try.

Comment: gofr1, thanks! great answer.

Comment: Please, mark it as 'accepted' if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT  p.Id_purchase,
        e.Id_employee
FROM employees e
CROSS JOIN purchase p
INNER JOIN key_search k 
  ON p.article LIKE '%' + REPLACE(k.[query],'*','%') + '%'
```

For current sample, result be like:

```
| Id_purchase | Id_employee |
|-------------|-------------|
|           1 |           1 |
|           1 |           2 |
|           1 |           3 |
|           2 |           1 |
|           2 |           2 |
|           2 |           3 |
|           3 |           1 |
|           3 |           2 |
|           3 |           3 |
```